# How to extract multiple Wikipedia articles at once?

Tags: python, text, nlp, wikipedia, pywikibot

I am using Python 2.7 Anaconda.

I have used the Wikipedia Python package to extract a list of article titles:

```
titles = wikipedia.random(pages=1000).decode('utf-8')
titles_encoded = [x.encode('utf-8') for x in titles]
```

Is there a way of using

```
wikipedia.summary(title=titles_encoded,auto_suggest=True, redirect=True).encode('utf-8')
```

in order to extract multiple articles at once? I have used a for loop but it takes really long:

```
for n in range(1,500):
    test[n] = wikipedia.summary(title=titles_encoded[n],auto_suggest=True, redirect=True).encode('utf-8')
    print(n,"text extracted")
```

I am looking for a solution that is more efficient/faster.

Comment: I don't think there is an option to fetch summaries in bulk. If you need bulk data, the [free data dumps](https://meta.wikimedia.org/wiki/Data_dump_torrents#enwiki) might be a better way to get content.

Comment: I have looked at this, but I have to admit, I don't seem capable of parsing those xml formats. Which is why I'm looking for raw text